# why doesn't my quicksort implementation in C work

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

Here I made a quicksort implementation that uses (at least tries to) a little trick that is possible because I know the input is a list of numbers in the set {1,2,...,1023}. In particular I am not using a pivot that is necessarily in the list itself. Here is the main part of the function

```
int partition2(int length, int arr[], int mask) {
  int left = 0;
  int right = length;

  while (left < right) {
    while ((left < right) && (!((arr[left])&mask)) ) {
      left++;
    }
    while ((left < right) && ((arr[right-1])&mask)) {
      right--;
    }
    if (left < right) {
      right--;
      swap(left, right, arr);
      left++;
    }    
  }
  left--;
  return left;
}

void qSort2(int length, int arr[], int mask) {
  int boundary;
  if (length <= 1) {
    return; /* empty or singleton array: nothing to sort */
  }
  boundary = partition2(length, arr, mask);
  qSort2(boundary, arr,mask/2);
  qSort2(length - boundary - 1, &arr[boundary + 1], mask/2);
}


main(){
  int length = 200;
  int *arr;
  arr = generateNumbers(length);
  qSort2(length, arr, 512);   
  int i;d
  for(i=0;i<length;i++){
    printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Sorry for the lengthy code. The function generateNumbers just makes a vector of size length with numbers from the given range and swap simply swaps two elements from the array. Now I am trying to exploit the fact that all numbers are smaller that 1024. So roughly speaking half of them will contain a 1 in binary representation in the position corresponding to 2^9=512. So we can use that to split the list in two lists. Then we check for both list what the digit corresponding to 2^8 is and split the list again. I am using the variable mask for this and the operator n&mask is zero if the is smaller then mask and non zero if it is larger that mask. For some reason though, it does not seem to work. Does anyone have any idea why? The output list is almost sorted but there are just some mistakes at certain places. If anyone could help me out that would be great. Thanks!

Here is the generateNumbers function:

```
void *makeDynamicIntArray(int length) {
  void *ptr = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("\nMalloc failed: out of memory?\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  return ptr;
}

int *generateNumbers(int length) {
  int i, *arr = makeDynamicIntArray(length);
  for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand() % 1024;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the `mask` business. This is because checking an arbitrary bit in a number drawn from a uniform distribution (which is what `generateNumbers` creates) is akin to a fair coin toss. So your `left` and `right` indices are typically only inc-/dec-remented once for every pass of the outer loop. To pick the pivot, just pick an arbitrary element, or the median of a small subsample of your elements.

Comment: Put a few assert()s or printf()s in. IMHO the return value from partition2() (=left) can be negative in some cases.

Comment: Allright ill try that, nice name btw @wildplasser :D

Comment: @wildplasser Left turns out is actually never negative, I checked with an assert statement.

Comment: @SchighSchagh the reasoning for using the mask strategy is as follows. This way, even if the array is sorted the order is not N^2. After the first pass we have a list of elements larger that 512 and one smaller. Then we can check the 2^8 binary digit in each list and divide it up again.